# shorthand in *.bib: get the string of other fields

Tags: biblatex

In the `.bib` file I maintain for some file the field `localfile`:

```
@book{ST,
    author = {Mister X},
    series = {Notes},
    localfile = {./SetTheory.pdf},
    shorthand = {\href{run:./SetTheory.pdf}{ST}},
    title = {Set Theory},
    year = {2018}
}
```

This code is working fine, but I would like to automatize it.

1. The simple solution would be to get from a variable the `localfile`, something like that:

   ```
   shorthand = {\href{run:\localfie}{ST}},
   ```
2. Same for the `shorthand`

   ```
   shorthand = {\href{run:\localfie}{\shorthand}},
   ```

   in such a way that I can use the shorthands generated by Latex
3. The best solution would be to modify the printing of the shorthand, with the logic: if localfile present

   ```
   shorthand = {\href{run:\localfile}{ST}},
   ```

otherwise let latex work as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example uses the known field `file` instead of the unknown `localfile`. If you wanted to use `localfile` you would have to define a custom data model first.

In the `shorthand` field you only give the shorthand, no additional `\href` markup is needed.

If `file` is present, the shorthand in the citation links to the external file, otherwise it just links to the bibliography entry as usual.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandlink}{%
  \iffieldundef{file}
    {\bibhyperref{#1}}
    {\ifhyperref
       {\href{run:\thefield{file}}{#1}}
       {#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[shorthandlink]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date      = {1980},
  shorthand = {CS},
}
@online{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  url       = {http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  file      = {./bronto.pdf},
  shorthand = {EB}, 
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{elk,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The citations read "EB; CS", where "EB" is coloured in dark green and "CS" in light green, light green indicates an internal link, dark green an external]

the PDF has

```
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[0 .7 .7]
/Rect [147.716 654.302 163.542 665.093]
/Subtype/Link/A<</F(./bronto.pdf)/S/Launch>>
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Link
/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[0 1 0]
/Rect [167.636 654.302 182.356 665.093]
/A << /S /GoTo /D (cite.0@appleby) >>
>>
endobj
```

---

If you only want this for the labels in the bibliography you need

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\iffilelink}{%
  \ifboolexpr{    test {\ifhyperref}
              and test {\ifbibliography}
              and not test {\iffieldundef{file}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{%
    \iffilelink
      {\href{run:\thefield{file}}{#1}}
      {#1}}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date      = {1980},
  shorthand = {CS},
}
@online{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  url       = {http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  file      = {./bronto.pdf},
  shorthand = {EB}, 
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{elk,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The logic is slightly more involved now because we need to stop the link from being used when the length of the label is measured, so we add the `\ifbibliography` check.

[image: The shorthand label "EB" of <code>elk</code> is linked to the external file in the bibliography list at the end, the in-text citations both link to the bibliography.]

For a `numeric` style you would redefine `labelnumberwidth` instead of `labelalphawidth`.

Comment: I think that there is a misunderstaning. My Bibliography looks like `[ST] Mister X. Set Theory. Notes. 2018.` The clikable text should be [ST], the head of the bibligraphy item in the References, behind `\printbibliography`

Comment: no problem using `file` insteald of `localfile`. I used KBibTeX.

Comment: @PeptideChain There may well have been, please provide a fully compilable working example that shows what you are doing. My crystal ball is a bit fogged up at the moment due to the heat.

Comment: Thank you very much. Here is in my code https://pastebin.com/fA27fn0f  Note that  `../MatPhys/MatPhys` is a bib file that I use in more  books. Your code has been inserted in a package used by all my books. I get the warning: `Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'cite:shorthand' undefined.` and `(biblatex)                Using \newbibmacro on input line 225.` No error. I try to build a working example.

Comment: @PeptideChain Please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) in plain text format to your question. Do not link to files we don't have. And please consider posting an MWE in future questions right away. It is quite frustrating when you answer a question and you then get the reply: Sorry I meant something else. You should have at least mentioned the style you use and where you want the link to appear.

Comment: Thank you again. I understand. The code after your edit works also by me now.